# Drupal7 - Can't change profile/languages anymore on installation

Tags: drupal-7, installation, acquia

So, i success to install Drupal 7 Acquia the first time i did it.

I had to remove all and remake the installation

But now when i launch the installation, profile and language settings are auto-loaded and i can't change them anymore :

```
http://localhost:8080/acquia-drupal-7.22.21/install.php?profile=acquia&locale=en
```

[image]

I past so many hours to search a solution, without success. I know i can translate after the installation but it's not that i want to do.
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Is there a settings.php in your /sites/default/ folder already, which contains both variables?

I experienced the same behavior with already existing database-config.

Comment: There are probably values for this, but it's not on this file. Maybe in a file of the acquia profile.

Anyway i give up this problem and apply languages after installation.

Thank you even for your reply